# Tests pass at REPL, fail on command line with lein test

Tags: clojure

If I run `lein test` from within my project's directory, I get odd errors like this:

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: clojure.set`

I use `clojure.set` in one place in my app.

If I try to run just a single test defined in `deftest` from the command line, then I get that it cannot find the test on the classpath.

If I run `(run-tests)` from the REPL, everything passes.

I'd like to be able to run from command line if possible. Can anyone advise what is the issue?

Comment: Do you `require` clojure.set? It's not loaded by default (though nrepl does load it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need to require clojure.set in the namespace(s) where you are using it.

It works without a require in the repl because nrepl requires it in it's own code in [this file](https://github.com/clojure/tools.nrepl/blob/master/src/main/clojure/clojure/tools/nrepl.clj). But when running `lein test` that require is not happening.

Answer (score 0):

`(run-tests)` only runs the tests in the namespace your repl is in.  Perhaps the problem is in a test that is outside of that namespace.

Comment: (run-all-tests) also passes at the REPL, which I think tests multiple namespaces, right?

Comment: `(run-all-tests)` runs all loaded tests. It will not test any test namespaces that have not been `require`ed by your repl. `lein test` finds and loads test namespaces for you, but it needs to be done manually in a repl.